# Retrieving a document from a database

Tags: java, ms-access

I am getting an error: "The constructor Document(ByteArrayInputStream) is undefined"

Code snippet below:

```
public static Document readfromDB(String filename) throws Exception
{

    String sql = SELECT * FROM File where FileName = '"filename +"'";
    ResultSet rs = executeQuery(sql);
    if (!rs.isBeforeFirst())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException (MessageFormat.format("No record found"));
    rs.next
    byte[] buffer = resultset.getbytes("FileContent");
    ByteArrayInputStream newStream- new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
    Document doc = new Document(newStream);
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: What is this class "Document"? Maybe it can be created from simple Stream or byte array (buffer).

Comment: @MissD I think `Document` is an interface. As far as I know, constructor definitions are not allowed in Java interfaces. Please refer to this link: [Java API for Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html)

Comment: How is this document stored in the Access database? Is it in an `Attachment` field or is it in an `OLE Object` field?

Comment: The Document is stored using:

Comment: The Document is stored using: 
"INSERT INTO File (FileContent) VALUES(?)";
statement.setString(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(outputstream.toByteArray()), outputstream.size());
statement.execute();
Looking at this code block my understanding of it was that Document is an Object of some sort? Was I mistaken?
Please note that I am fairly new in using java and programming and all these terminologies you are using may not be easy for me to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Chances are good that `FileContent` is an `OLE Object` (binary object) field, but just to be sure: Open the database in Access, right-click the `File` table and choose "Design View", then look at the "Data Type" for the `FileContent` field. What does it say?

Comment: FileContent is a field in access. The document is stored in byte form in the FileContent field, and then retrieved to a buffer..

Comment: Read my previous comment again. What TYPE of field is it?

Comment: Sorry. Its an OLE Object